# How to get all the branches with a certain head in git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

There is a commit with commit hash = c1

**How to list all the branches that have their head "pointing" (or equal) to c1 ?**

Aware of how to get the branches that contain a commit, but not able to figure out the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [git manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---points-atltobjectgt)

`git branch --points-at <object>`

So for example from your question

`git branch --points-at c1`